# How to block targetUpdateId using Blockui using ajax.actionLink or ajax.beginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I want to develop an ajax pipeline such that whenever there is any ajax request made through ajax.beginform or ajax.actionLink it should start with my ajax.start function in which i can be able to read the targetupdateid so that i can shoew blockui and any developer should not bother about this ajax.start.I was trying to use this piece of code but itis not working

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (xhr, setting) {
    console.log(this.activeElement);
    if (this.activeElement.type == 'submit') {
        activeElement = this.activeElement.form.attributes["data-ajax-update"].value;

    } else {
       / activeElement = this.activeElement.attributes["data-ajax-update"].value;
    }
    if (activeElement != null) {
        $(activeElement).blockUI();
    }

});
```

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: if i undershoot you question correctly do you want block whole UI while Ajax.BeginForm or Ajax.actionLink performing the functionality?
can you please show some snaps of Ajax.BeginForm or Ajax.actionLink code..

Comment: Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "main-body", HttpMethod = "Post" })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the solution but i want to block the UpdateTargetId  which i resolve by adding a listener to the click .

```
  var activeElement,
    targetElement,
    callbackfunc = function (event) {
        activeElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
    };
window.addEventListener('click', callbackfunc, true);
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {if (activeElement !== null && activeElement !== undefined) {
        if (activeElement.type == 'submit') {
            targetElement = activeElement.form.attributes["data-ajax-update"].value;
        }
        if (activeElement.tagName == 'A') {
            targetElement = activeElement.attributes["data-ajax-update"].value;
        }
    }

    if (targetElement !== undefined || targetElement !== null) {
        $(targetElement).block({
            showOverlay: false,
            css: { border: '0px', width: '40px', height: '40px' },
            message: '<div class="progress"><div>'
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   <div id="mainbody">
   </div>  

    <div id="SomeId" style="display:none">

        // put you style to block the UI here 
        // or put loader image
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/ajax_loader_big.gif")" alt="" />
    </div>


    @Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "mainbody", HttpMethod = "Post", LoadingElementId = "SomeId" })
```

you can use Ajax-Loader or some css style with loader image which will block the UI. you need to paas that div Id in  **LoadingElementId** which block the UI until ajax functionality is not completed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i want to block the UpdateTargetId  which i resolve by adding a listener to the click .